# Magento 2 import bulk products with custom attribute

Tags: magento2, product, custom, bulk

I have created 1 custom attribute (`current_user_id`) and saving value when product is saved. 
I have use`catalog_product_save_before` event that save value for my custom attribute(`current_user_id`). code is

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object
        $current_users=$this->authSession->getUser();
        $current_admin_id=$current_users->getData('user_id');
        $_product->setCurrentUserId($current_admin_id) ;
    }
```

It work perfect for `add` single product.

But now I want to `add bulk products` How this possible for import bulk product ?

I think we make custom attribute column in `csv file` and use which event that fire when `import` after check data. and `foreach` for setting value in custom attribute ?
Please Guide me I want to save custom attribute value in bulk products
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK `catalog_product_save_before` event is not executing on the bulk import process this event is executing only when you save the product from backend.

The correct event would be [`catalog_product_import_bunch_save_after`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/CatalogImportExport/Model/Import/Product.php#L1970) for the bulk import process

And from your question, you want to set the current admin user Id in `current_user_id` attribute so I think this is the perfect event for the hook.

So what you need to do create `events.xml`

```
<event name="catalog_product_import_bunch_save_after">
        <observer name="some_admin_user" instance="Example\Sample\Observer\AssignAdminId"/>
    </event>
```

Now you need to create observer `AssignAdminId.php`

In this observer, you can easily get the imported products and you can update product attributes by using mass action method ['updateAttributes'](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Action.php#L88) method

```
<?php

namespace Example\Sample\Observer;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AssignAdminId implements ObserverInterface
{

    private $import;

    /**
     * @var Action
     */
    private $massAction;

    /**
     * AssignAdminId constructor.
     * @param Action $massAction
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action $massAction
    )
    {
        $this->massAction = $massAction;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->import = $observer->getEvent()->getAdapter();
        if ($products = $observer->getEvent()->getBunch()) {
            $array_product = [1,2,3,4,5]; //find imported product ID here
            $adminId = 1 ;// find current admin Id here
            $this->massAction->updateAttributes($array_product, array('current_user_id' => $adminId), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well practic dear keyur Shah. let me try it .

Comment: but how can get `imported ID product`

Comment: I am not sure but you can find all products in `$products` object so please try to debug how you can get imported Ids but as per I know it should be easy

Comment: events.xml will be in etc\events.xml or etc\adminhtml\events.xml ?

Comment: please put in `etc\adminhtml\events.xml` and if your observer is not working then put under etc directory

Comment: it stuck . when i import then just spinner move round and nothing do . i check log but also not make any log and not missa any file check from inspect . . ..  you can see here https://ibb.co/M5qTL4m

Comment: i don't why it stuck the process . 
kindly guide me more

Comment: please check log, di:compile, cache:clean and try, how can I guide you without checking,

Comment: ! dear i run di:compile and cache also . and `etc\adminhtml\event.xml`  But again spinner move round and nothing do more. i check log but it not create anything in log.

Comment: even i comment all code in observer execute method. but spinner move and nothing to do more . 
can you guide me more please what might be  problem ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92568/discussion-between-hafiz-umer-and-keyur-shah).

Comment: yes absolute work dear ! but here just 1 issue how can get `imported ID product` !
I test it by giving hardcode imported product ids. it work . 
Just now want to get `imported ID product` .

Comment: Did you check what kind of object you are getting in `$products`?

Comment: yes i check $products . it return all the items that is write in CSV file.

Comment: we get sku from $product and possible  pass `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepositry` and `get(sku)` return the product detail and then we get id of `imported product` ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create the **`csv file`** with two fields **"sku"** & **"custom_attribute"** & add your values to that files as you want.

- Go to the below location

> Admin > SYSTEM > Data Transfer > Import

- From the drop-down select product.
- In Import behavior select Add/Update.
- Chose your CSV file in Select File to Import.
- Click on the check data for checking the data. (If facing any issue with the sheet try to solve it & try again)
- Click on the Import Button.

You are done with the attributes value import for all the products.

---

**Update**

Your csv File will looks like this.

sku | Custom_Id

abc |    25

xyz |    25

You need to pass the sku & custom_attribute as header column & in every row it will have the sku & custom attribute values.

Comment: just 2 feilds ? and other products attributes ? and i want to save current login admin id as a value of `custom_attribute` then how can give value in csv file ?  it should add on run time. may fire any event etc . .

Comment: as the operation is Add/Update so if the product is already present there in the magento it will simply update your existing product with that particular attribute value & if it is not there it will create a new product (In general case when import is done with all the other attribute values also) but in your case it will show error of product not exist.

Comment: Since this is a manual import process so there is no any default event is going to run with this import, it will simply add those values to your custom attributes filed which you have/will passed/pass through the csv file.

Comment: For getting the particular admin users Id you can simply get it from `SYSTEM > Permission > All Users` get the id from there & pass that value into your csv &  import it, It will simply add that id to all the products Into your custom attribute field. Which you have passed in your csv file.

Comment: i actually i make multi vendor site . as you say each vendor manually give own id in csv file .

Comment: Yes correct if they are going to use your back-end with your ACl permission to import their products you can simply provide them there id's say 1, 2, 3 etc. & ask them to have such field & import that csv from the above directed place.

Comment: dear i make custom column in csv files and set values manually. you can see here https://ibb.co/Y0gCKWP  But these value of custom attribute is not save in database.

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92566/discussion-between-hafiz-umer-and-abhishek-tripathi).

Answer (score 1):

The correct event would be catalog_product_import_bunch_save_after for the bulk import process.
but I need to update qty so how I will update that because "**updateAttributes**()" another attribute is updated but **qty is not update**e

So can you please help me asap?

Thanks in advance!