# Magento 2 : How to know who admin_user added a product?

Tags: magento2, eav

I created a new `admin_user` role, this role has access to the products page and can add a new product.

So, I want to save the ID of the current `admin_user` to know who's added the product.

The first method I think about is to add a new foreign key to `catalog_product_website` table on DB with the `ID` of `admin_user` table.

And after that, I will use an event to save the ID on this table, on save the product.

But with some search, I found there's `EAV` method.

So, it's better to use the first method? Or it's better to use `EAV` and create `attribute` not visibly and save on it the ID of the current user?

Comment: EAV should not be used here. please read the docs on what EAV does/when it's used

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 import bulk products with custom attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270471/magento-2-import-bulk-products-with-custom-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by creating a new [product attribute](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/attributes-product.html). let say `admin_user_id`. now you need to feel this value on product saving from backend by using Magento events. If you are not familiar with Magento events and observer please read [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html)  from the Magento DevDocs.

In your case, you should use `catalog_product_save_before` event. this event is executing before saving the product. In this event, you will get a product object so you can use this object and set the current admin user Id(you can get it from current admin session). For example,

Create `events.xml` under `etc/adminhtml/events.xml`

```
    <event name="catalog_product_save_before">
        <observer name="assign_admin_user_id_on_save" instance="Example\Sample\Observer\AssignAdminIdOnSave"/>
    </event>
```

Now you need to create an observer class which should implement [`Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/ObserverInterface.php#L15)

```
<?php

namespace Example\Sample\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session as adminSession;

class AssignAdminIdOnSave implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var adminSession
     */
    private $adminSession;

    /**
     * AssignAdminIdOnSave constructor.
     * @param adminSession $adminSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        adminSession $adminSession
    )
    {
        $this->adminSession = $adminSession;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $adminId=$this->adminSession->getUser()->getId();
        $product->setAdminUserId($adminId) ;
    }
}
```

***Please note that this will work only when you are creating/saving the product from the backend.***

If you also want admin user Id on product import then you need to create another observer for `catalog_product_save_before`. I already wrote the answer for this so you can check from [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/270488/2589)

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, I create the `admin_user_id` attribute using `EAV`, and I write the observer, where I can check if the ID is inserted or not?